# How i can rollback or know the folder who i move suddenly as mistake?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

i am suddenly trying to find out a directory in sollution in Visual studio. and move a folder in another folder as mistake. what are plugin for that known me or shown me the folder i move as mistake.

any idea to solve this type of issue in Visual studio 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [VSCommands](http://vscommands.com/feature-comparison/) (available via the extension manager), it ***prevents this completely*** - as moving folders is pretty rare. IIRC you need to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> (or something) otherwise no drag happens.

Invaluable (although "Prevent accidental Drag & Drop" is only in the "Pro" version, looking at the comparison sheet - but honestly, it's a good plugin - I recommend it)

Answer (score 2):

A way to prevent this is to use some type of version control such as Mercurial or Git. This way you can rollback your actions or see what changes you've made since your last commit.

Answer (score 1):

If you realize your mistake immediately you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (undo).  Otherwise it may be too late and you will need to manually examine your folders until you find the one that is out of place.

Comment: Last time I did this by accident, there was nothing in the undo buffer. YMMV.